# No parameterless constructor defined for this object, after form with ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm working on a project and I'm not used to C#. I tried to work after my old working code. I couldn't find any difference.

My html form:

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TicketID)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Ticketdetail</legend>

          <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Anmerkung)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Anmerkung)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Anmerkung)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

the actions:

```
public ActionResult CreateDetail(int id)
{
    if (id == -1) return Index(-1);
    return View(new cTicketDetail(id, User.Identity.Name));
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateDetail(cTicketDetail collection)
{


    //int TicketID = collection.TicketID;
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            collection.Write();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Details", collection.TicketID);
    }
    catch
    {
        return this.CreateDetail(collection.TicketID);
    }
}
```

[the error after commiting my Form](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B58uToSxhRvtSlZfdl8xX2V2RlU)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `cTicketDetail` type that you have used in your `CreateDetail` action doesn't have a parameterless constructor. Controller actions cannot take such types as arguments because the default model binder doesn't know how to instantiate them.

The best practice here is to define a view model and then have your controller action take this view model as parameter instead of using your domain entities.

If you don't want to use view models you will have to modify your `cTicketDetail` type so that it has a default constructor:

```
public class cTicketDetail
{
    // The default parameterless constructor is required if you want
    // to use this type as an action argument
    public cTicketDetail()
    {
    }

    public cTicketDetail(int id, string username)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.UserName = username;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: wow thx! i thought it would be okey because it was like public cTicketDetail(int id = -1,string username="") but alright now it works with an extra constructur